# Affecting various div classes when hovering over one single div class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to affect various div classes when hovering over one particular div class.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2R4Q/)

CSS

```
.left {float:left;}
.middle {float:left;}
.right {float:right;}

.left, .middle, .right {width:33%; 
    height:40px; background-color:transparent;}

.middle:hover {background-color:red;}

.middle:hover ~ .right {background-color: green;}

.text {display:none;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <a href="#">linked text</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <span class="text">Here we have some text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

When hovering over the middle div class, the left, middle and right div classes all have to get different background colours.

Besides that, the The div on the right also has text in it. This text needs to be hidden and should only show when the div in the middle is hovered on.

So, to recap..

On page load, the left, middle and right divs should have a transparent background and the div on the right should not have any text. When hovering the middle div, the 3 divs all get a different background color and the text in the right div should become visible.

I'm trying to do this with pseudo-selectors, but I can only change the background color in the middle and right divs. I can't affect the left div and the text visibility does not work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Updated the fiddle to fix the text display, but the general sibling selector (~) only works with siblings that come *afterwards*, which is why it's not working for the `.left` div.

Comment: Thanks @Dre. I managed to get that part working, but now I'm left with one more issue. Maybe you can help. I had left it as a comment below the previous reply..but I'll copy/paste it here.

I have a top menu, where one of the menu (li) items has to get a different colour whenever the middle div gets hovered as well. So, the menu container (basic top page navigation) is separate from the middle div (which is in its own container). 

Once you hover on the middle div, one of the menu items up top has to get a different text colour. Is this possible?

Updated Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/r2R4Q/4/

Comment: Not possible with just CSS; you would need  a touch of JS to pull this off, essentially adding an additional class to the menu iem so that you can style it.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this if you change your markup such that the .middle class is the first child of the container. This is because there is no parent selector (yet) in css. **Note**: even though it's the first child in the markup, we can still visually place it in the middle by floating (or positioning) the other 2 elements:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/r2R4Q/3/)**

### Markup:

```
<div id="container">
     <div class="middle">
        <a href="#">linked text</a>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <span class="text">Here we have some text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container
{
    text-align: center;
}
.left {float:left;}
.middle { display: inline-block; }
.right {float:right;}

.left, .middle, .right 
{
    width:33%; 
    height:40px; 
    background-color:transparent;
}

.middle:hover {background-color:red;}

.middle:hover ~ div {
    background-color: green;
}

.middle:hover ~ .right .text {
    display: block;
}

.text {display:none;}
```

Comment: Wow...that did the trick. Thank you very much.

One more question if possible. I have a top menu, where one of the menu (li) items has to get a different color whenever the middle div gets hovered as well.

Can you point me in the right direction with that as well?